# label a part of commutative diagram

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\textheight 9.3in \textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\underline{V} 
\arrow[rrrrdd,  bend left]
\arrow[rrdddd, bend right] \arrow[rrdd, dotted] &  &&  & \\
& & &  & \\
&  & A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] &  & B \arrow[dd] \\
&  &  &  & \\
&  & C \arrow[rr] &  & D                
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

above code is giving me following diagram

[image]

I used "phantom" technique to number part of commutative diagram. It did not work. I want to write

- (1) in the diagram enclosed by V,A,B
- (2) in the diagram enclosed by V,A,C
- (3) in the diagram enclosed by A,B,C,D

Can some one help me to see how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

[image]

You can add the labels to your diagram with no arrows:

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
\underline{V} 
\arrow[rrrrdd,  bend left]
\arrow[rrdddd, bend right] \arrow[rrdd, dotted] &  &&  & \\
& & (1) &  & \\
& (2) & A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] &  & B \arrow[dd] \\
&  &  & (3) & \\
&  & C \arrow[rr] &  & D                
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Comment: absolutely.. this seem to be much easier than phantom thing,..

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun: `tikz-cd` is based on Ti*k*Z so

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.8cm]
\node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (b) at (2,0) {$B$};
\node (c) at (0,-2) {$C$};
\node (d) at (2,-2) {$D$};
\node (v) at (-2,2) {$\underline{V}$};
\draw[->] (a)--(b);
\draw[->] (b)--(d);
\draw[->] (a)--(c);
\draw[->] (c)--(d);
\draw[dotted,->] (v)--(a);
\draw[->] (v) to[bend right] (c);
\draw[->] (v) to[bend left] (b);
\node at (1,-1) {(3)};
\node at (0,1) {(1)};
\node at (-1,0) {(2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

But I prefer this way (though the way I code it is not efficient)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.8cm,>=stealth]
\node (V) at (-2,2) {\phantom{$\underline{V}$}};
\node (B) at (2,0) {\phantom{$B$}};
\node (C) at (0,-2) {\phantom{$C$}};
\fill[yellow!50] (0,0) rectangle (2,-2);
\fill[green!20] (V) to[bend left] (B)--(2,0)--(0,0)--(V);
\fill[blue!20] (V) to[bend right] (C)--(0,-2)--(0,0)--(V);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={fill=white,circle,draw}]
    \node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
    \node (b) at (2,0) {$B$};
    \node (c) at (0,-2) {$C$};
    \node (d) at (2,-2) {$D$};
    \node (v) at (-2,2) {$\underline{V}$};
\end{scope}
\draw[->] (a)--(b);
\draw[->] (b)--(d);
\draw[->] (a)--(c);
\draw[->] (c)--(d);
\draw[dashed,->] (v)--(a);
\draw[->] (v) to[bend right] (c);
\draw[->] (v) to[bend left] (b);
\node at (1,-1) {(3)};
\node at (0,1) {(1)};
\node at (-1,0) {(2)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :) :) thanks...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik You are welcome. Now you have got three answers, choose the best of them and tick the checkmark on the left of the answer (aka accept that answer). Doing so will mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 7):

With phantom arrows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[nodes in empty cells]
\underline{V}
  \arrow[rrrrdd,  bend left]
  \arrow[rrdddd, bend right]
  \arrow[rrdd, dotted]
  \arrow[rrrrdd,phantom,"(1)" description]
  \arrow[rrdddd,phantom,"(2)" description]
\\
&&&&\\
&& A \arrow[dd] \arrow[rr] & \arrow[dd,phantom,"(3)" description] &
B \arrow[dd] \\
&&&&\\
&& C \arrow[rr] && D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]