# Insert equation labels inside a tikz(cd) diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tikz-cd

I have the following commuting diagram and I want to insert equation labels as (phantom) edge labels inside the diagram (the label here doesn't work, it's pseudocode):

```latex
\begin{tikzcd}
      A \arrow["h",dr] \arrow[dd,"j"'] \arrow["f",rr] & \arrow[d,phantom, "\label{eq:foo}" description] & B\arrow[dl, "g"] \\
      \arrow[r,phantom, "\label{eq:bar}" description]& C \\
      D\arrow[ru,"k"]
    \end{tikzcd}
```

And I want it to visually look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? Basically I want to refer to different parts of the diagram commuting using different equation references.

Comment: Should these equation numbers follow the normal `equation` counter, i.e. the one of `amsmath` or are those numbers independent and maybe just unique per CD? (You could give the CD a number and then have subequations numbers inside the diagram.) What are these number referencing? A node? An arrow? A label? In your mock up they seem just randomly placed near *C*.

Comment: They are referencing parts of the commutative diagram, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480073/label-a-part-of-commutative-diagram. I was thinking of having them follow the normal `equation` counter but your idea of giving the CD a diagram would work as a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be where the `tikzcd` is using an unnumbered display math environment, i.e. `equation*` or `\[ … \]` and we will just place nodes with the equation number in it.

This seems to be compatible with `hyperref` but needs adjustments for `cleveref` (and then we might be able to introduce a separate category for those references as well).

All those macros are `amsmath` internals:

- `\@eqnwstrue` toggles the output of equation numbers inside math environments that don't have one for
- `\make@display@tag` which prints the actual equation number and
- `\ltx@label` is the original `\label` macro before `amsmath` added its own changes.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\makeatletter
\tikzcdset{
  eq node/.style={
    commutative diagrams/math mode=false, anchor=center},
  eq/.style={
    phantom,
    /tikz/every to/.append style={
      edge node={node[commutative diagrams/eq node]
        {\@eqnswtrue\make@display@tag\ltx@label{#1}}}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
A       \arrow["h", dr] \arrow[dd,"j"'] \arrow["f",rr]
  &     \arrow[d, eq=eq:foo]
    & B \arrow[dl, "g"] \\
        \arrow[r, eq=eq:bar]
  & C \\
D       \arrow[ru,"k"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
Equations \ref{eq:foo} and \eqref{eq:bar}.
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]